# Pycharm terminal is not repeating characters when key kept depressed

Tags: pycharm

I just noticed the behavior described in the title when attempting to traverse words using `set -o vi` command editing mode. I had the "j" or the "k" depressed and it only moved [left|right] one character no matter how long depressed.  Then I tried just typing normally (vi "insert" mode) and the keys do not repeat there either.

This seems to be new "behavior" (/bug) in the latest version of Pycharm 2021.3.1: I have been using Pycharm since its inception and did not notice it before.

Is there any setting or workaround to regain the repeat feature of a depressed key in the terminal?

Comment: Have you tried playing with your `Settings | Tools | Terminal` settings? [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28661127/ideavim-plugin-in-pycharm-doesnt-support-continuous-scroll-for-long-press) seems to indicate that a problem with `IdeaVim` would be on the OS side, but it sounds like you are actually using vim in the terminal, not the files. [Here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/terminal-emulator.html#configure-the-terminal-emulator) talks about what each of the options do, but it's not clear to me what the problem would be if it's here

Comment: Key repeat works everywhere and in terminal and iterm and even Intellij terminal session.  This is just for [most recent?] version of Pycharm.  I do not use the `ideaVIM`: this has nothing to do with ideaVIM since it's within the terminal session not the editor.